# Unused Condition in Inverse Proof

Tags: general-topology

I have a conjecture on my homework that reads "If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a one-to-one function and $f(X)=Y$, then $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$".  It seems obviously true and I have a proof that I think works to verify it...I just don't understand why the condition $f(X)=Y$ is given since I didn't use it in my proof, and can't understand why $f(X)=Y$, which implies $f$ is onto, would make a difference either way and why my instructor included it in the hypothesis.

Answer (score 3):

The hypotheses is there because without it, $f^{-1}: Y \to X$ is not well-defined --- there might be  an element $y \in Y$ with the property that there's no element $x \in X$ with $f(x) = y$, so $f^{-1}(y)$ would not be defined.

But your question is a GREAT one -- you should always ask, "Why didn't i use this hypothesis?" as you did.

I have to confess that I spent a moment or two thinking "Hey....*is* it really necessary?" before the "aha" moment.

Comment: But if $f$ is one-to-one, then $f(X)=Y$.

Comment: No. That's the definition of *onto*. Actually, one-to-one is a slightly awkward term, because *some* folks think it includes being onto, but most others think it means solely that if $f(x) = f(x'),$, then $x = x'$. It's one reason why I prefer using "injective" and "surjective", and the combined "bijective", much as I never use the term "range", because some folks  think it means the same thing as "image" while others think it means "codomain."

Comment: Well, I thought it meant bijective.

Comment: I think most people would interpret $f^{-1}$ as a map between power sets...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: And that shows that there's an ambiguity, doesn't it?

Comment: I agree that there's a function between power sets that *could* be called $f^{-1}$, but that's clearly the one that the problem was asking about, since it says "$f^{-1}(f(x))$" rather than "$f^{-1}(\{f(x)\})$".

Comment: Most people skip the brackets when talking about $1$ element sets. Either way this is a good answer,

Answer (score 0):

Well, when writing $f^{-1}$, one, "silently" implies that $f^{-1}:Y\to X$, so, in order to be well defined, it is needed that $f(X)=Y$. Otherwise, it should be made clear that $f^{-1}$ is defined as
$$f^{-1}:f(X)\to X$$
since $f$ is only one-to-one.

Comment: Personally, I prefer to consider $f^{-1}$ as the inverse relation of the relation $f,$ so that $f^{-1}$ is always defined. Then one can ask about the domain of the relation $f^{-1}$ and/or whether the relation $f^{-1}$ is one-to-one and/or whether the relation is "single-valued".

Comment: I see your point!

Answer (score 0):

You do not use ontoness for $f^{-1}[\{f(x)\}] = \{x\}$, which is an equality of sets that holds for all injective functions on $X$, where by definition: $f^{-1}[A] = \{x \in X: f(x) \in A\}$ for a subset $A$ of $Y$.

But $f^{-1}(f(x)) =x$ suggests that we actually consider an inverse function from $Y$ to $X$ (images of sets have $[]$, ditto for inverse images of sets). For such a function $f^{-1}$ to exist, $f$ must be onto and one-to-one, and $f^{-1}(y)$ for $ y\in Y$ is then defined as the unique $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$ (ontoness gives at least one, one-to-one at most one; they're dual notions: look up monomorphisms and epimorphisms for more on that). In that case $f^{-1}(f(x))$ is the unique $x' \in X$ such that $f(x') = f(x)$, so must equal $x$. So then your statement is an immediate consequence of the definition of $f^{-1}$.

So $f[X] =Y$ is used implicitly in assuming the existence of $f^{-1}$.